# nuxt layout - having distinct layouts for mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

```
import { isMobile } from 'mobile-device-detect'

export default {
    layout(context) {
        const mobile = isMobile ? 'mobile-layout' : 'desktop-layout
        return mobile
    }
}
```

I am creating a nuxt app. i am trying to detect when the view is either mobile or desktop. if i make a change to the code in my ide and save then isMobile is true and and it will get set to mobile-layout. However once you refresh the page isMobile is false and it will get set to desktop-mobile.

Im assuming that the layout is being set before it has time to determine if isMobile is true or false and automatically being set too false.

I cant figure out how to make something like this work. No matter what i try it always fails.

Answer (score 0):

Why go for some general package when we have official support for this purpose by Nuxt community only? I would recommend you to use **[@nuxtjs/device](https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module)** module.

What makes it special? This.

> This module injects flags that indicate a device type into the context
> and the component instance.

And this is how you can change the Layout dynamically. It is mentioned in the package's documentation.
https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module#nuxtjsdevice

```
export default {
    layout: (ctx) => ctx.isMobile ? 'mobile' : 'default'
}
```

Comment: where do I place the code @Pratik149 ?

Comment: @wittgenstein - inside the `page` component.

Comment: thanks - but I'm getting a vite error. I'll use a custom solution instead of the module.